# Can you explain how we get gold(II) sulfide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis

Can you explain how we get gold(II) sulfide, when gold has oxidation numbers of 1 and 3?

Comment: One solution would be if you have two gold atoms at +1 and +3, they average to +2.

Comment: Then again, it is probably closer to interstitial compounds like $\ce{Fe3C}$ or $\ce{WC}$ than to actual ionic sulfides like $\ce{CaS}$.

Answer (score 2):

Brauer's Handbook of Preparative Inorganic Chemistry ([1, p. 1062] and references therein) lists the following method for gold(II) sulfide synthesis:

> $$\ce{$\underset{1/10}{}$\qquad$\underset{242.7}{\ce{8 AuCl3}}$ + $\underset{20.2\,l.}{\ce{9 H2S}}$ + $\underset{7.2}{\ce{4 H2O}}$ = $\underset{183.3}{\ce{8 AuS}}$ + $\underset{87.5}{\ce{24 HCl}}$ + $\underset{9.8}{\ce{H2SO4}}$}$$
>
> A neutral 1-3% solution of $\ce{AuCl3}$ is precipitated in the cold (the temperature must not exceed $\pu{40 ^\circ C}$) with $\ce{H2S}$ or an alkali sulfide. The precipitate is filtered, thoroughly washed with water, and
>   treated with alcohol, anhydrous ether, $\ce{CS2}$ and again with ether.
>   The product is dried at $\pu{130 ^\circ C}$ over $\ce{P2O5}$.
>
> *Alternate method*: A solution of $\ce{AuCl3}$ is added in drops to an
>   aqueous solution of sodium dithiosulfatoaurate(I) [...].
>
> Properties: Formula weight 229.07. Deep black. Insoluble in water and acids; soluble in aqua regia and solutions of potassium cyanide and alkali polysulfides. Resistant to KOH in the cold, decomposes after prolonged boiling, liberating gold. Thermal decomposition begins at $\pu{140 ^\circ C}$.

#### Reference

1. Handbook of Preparative Inorganic Chemistry, 2nd ed.; Brauer, G., Ed.; *Academic Press: New York; London*, **1965**; Vol. 2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of information about gold monosulfide($\ce{AuS}$) that can be found [here](http://gold.atomistry.com/gold_monosulphide.html):

> Hydrogen sulphide or an alkali-metal sulphide precipitates the
>   monosulphide from solutions of auric chloride, and it is also produced
>   by the action of hydrogen sulphide on sodium aurothiosulphate. It is a
>   black substance, insoluble in acids except aqua regia, but soluble in
>   alkali-metal sulphides.